# Difference between Brazilian Jiu Jitsu and Israeli Jiu Jitsu

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, krav-maga, style

I've been doing BJJ for a while, but I wanted to further improve my self defense   skills. I started learning Krav Maga, which is part of the Israeli Combat System (ICS). A big part of ICS is Israeli Jiu Jitsu. Can anybody tell me what the difference is between BJJ and IJJ, because they look pretty much the same from what I can tell.

Here are two sites that provide data on IJJ:

https://www.ijjko.com/en/israeli-organization

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krav_Maga

Comment: The IJJKO website screams BS. 5th dan and red-white? An organisation named after some Hungarian guy? What the heck?! Also, what do you expect? There are only so many functional responses to each attack, so effective training will ultimately involve the same moves regardless of the label.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking 5th dan red and white is used for juso, so why not IJJ? I can tell you that Israeli Jiu Jitsu is real.

Comment: Red-white is used from 6th dan to 8th dan in Judo and every sport which adapted Judo ranking I encountered so far.

Comment: But 6 is only one more than 5, isn't it?

Comment: Does it matter? Some martial arts have a lot of 10th dans, others have serveral years none. Some have 1. dan as capable trainers, other arts have trainers starting at higher ranks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Israeli Jiu-Jitsu" seems to appear in two contexts:

1. Describing BJJ and/or Japanese Jujutsu techniques as adapted and incorporated into some styles of Krav Maga (which has its [origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krav_Maga) in incorporating techniques from a variety of older martial arts: boxing, wrestling, judo etc), e.g. as taught by [Roy Elghanayan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJ-IUd3IQMI).
2. Describing Jiu-Jitsu organisations/schools/practitioners that are Israeli (as in your first link). This is similar to e.g. the British Judo Association, which doesn't purport to teach a distinct martial art from Judo taught elsewhere, only denoting the nationality of the organisation.